# Is there a content element in HTML5?

Tags: html

I was confused about the `content` element the guy is using. I couldn't find information on it and as far as I know there wasn't something like this in HTML5. Am I wrong?

iterating code, from this video:
http://youtu.be/eOG90Q8EfRo?t=15m1s

```
<article>
  <header> </header>
  <footer> </footer>
  <content> Is this correct? </content>
</article>
```

Comment: There is "something like this" in the WHATWG HTML living (un)standard, but it's called `<main>`, not `<content>`. In the W3C HTML5 standard, however, `<main>` is only for the dominant contents of the `<body>` element, so probably is inappropriate for marking the dominant contents of an article as per shown in the video.

Comment: But using `<main>` replacing the `div.mainContent` would be correct?

Comment: I think so, as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main, but only firefox and chrome are working

Comment: Fyi, a `<content>` tag does exist in HTML now. It's related to Shadow DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `<content>` element was proposed but [rejected](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Aug/0298.html) for HTML 5.

Such is the peril of trying to teach draft specifications.

Comment: I don't think `<content>` made it into any HTML draft. Looks more like wishful thinking.

Comment: The arguments against `content` in the linked article aren't really very good- amounting to semantically everything that isn't in another tag must be `content`, which is neither necessarily true, not helpful.  If you're going to have `header` and `footer` it seems only logical and sensible to me to have `content`

Comment: @nicodemus13 — Take it up with the spec writers then. (But the header and footer *are* content, even if they aren't the `main` content).

Answer (score 13):

There is a [`<content>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content) element, although it is used differently than how the presenter is using in the video linked in this question.

> The HTML `<content>` element is used inside of Shadow DOM as an insertion
>   point.  It is not intended to be used in ordinary HTML. It is used with Web
>   Components.

The presenter in the video probably should have been using the [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) element.

> The HTML `<main>` Element represents the main content of  the `<body>` of a document or application.  The main content area consists of content that is directly related to, or expands upon the central topic of a document or the central functionality of an application.  This content should be unique to the document, excluding any content that is repeated across a set of documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms (unless, of course, the document's main function is as a search form).

Comment: [The `<content>` element is no longer defined in the Shadow DOM spec](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/commit/a4ec41e529834c6a4788b1e2e0c189926e869c45). It seems to have been replaced by the `<slot>` element, which seeks to solve the same problem, but does so in a different way.

Comment: Note: `main` is used for main content in a document. Only one is allowed per document. Thus, it is not reusable like `section` or `header`. It's overall a pretty useless HTML tag. However, if the community came together and started using it as the main content of a section/article tag, that might force them to change the spec.

Comment: If you want to use `main` as the main thing between `header` and `footer`, note also that [`main` can't be put under an `article` tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-main-element). So you'll have to use something else for pages whose main content is a single article with a header and footer (even though in this case there is only one `main`). I suppose the best alternative is `section`. So for pages that contain only one article that has a header and footer, use: `<main><article> <header><section><footer>
 </article></main>`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `<main>`. It is used in HTML the separate the main content of your page.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...head content
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    ...header content
    </header>

    <nav>
    ...nav menu
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section id="news">
            <article id="who-let-the-dog-out">
            ...article content
            </article>

            <article id="LottoSurprice">
            ...article content
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="blog">
        ...section content
        </section>

        <aside id="advertisement">
        ...aside content
        </aside>
    </main>  <!-- end of page content -->

    <footer>
    ...footer content
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

— [`<main>` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

Comment: ...but you can only have one main per document, so this doesn't work for any other situation where you might need a header-something-footer combination.