# Why can't I add styling to the content tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying add some styling to the overall content on my page, but styling I add to the `<content>` tag in the CSS doesn't show up anywhere.

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/a8VhR/

Comment: There is no `<content>` tag in HTML5... Though you could do `content { display: block; }`

Comment: Previously on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170547/is-there-a-content-tag-in-html-or-what-is-this-guy-teaching

Comment: <content> tag was proposed but rejected for HTML5. http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Aug/0298.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<content>` is not a valid tag, as suggested in [@BenM answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22502218/1654265). Then just use a valid tag instead.

For the records, the hack to show it would be giving it a block level display attribute:

```
content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/a8VhR/4/)

Comment: Why does giving it `display: block` help?

Comment: @Imray because by default, the browser treats it as an inline element,  and thus cannot have width or height styles applied.

Comment: @Imray, please be advised that using `<content>` will produce invalid markup. You should avoid using such a hacky solution, and rather try to write valid HTML...

Comment: I totally agree with @BenM , this was just for the records, not for the win :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't style it because the browser doesn't understand `<content>`. It was [rejected](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Aug/0298.html) from the HTML5 specification.

You'll need to replace it with another element (such as `<article>`).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8VhR/3/)

Comment: He can style <content>. Only problem in example that content behaves like inline element. Display block will fix everything

Comment: True, although he(topic starter) need to understand that he actually added some styles to content tag. Just didn't notice them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target `div` inside your `content` instead:

```
content div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is universal defined html tag, and it's not all the time working with creating your own custom tags, i believe easier to use it as a div+class then

Answer (score -1):

I checked the fiddle.

The html written there is wrong  as of my knowledge. Because I don't think there is any tag in HTMK known as `<content>`.

Also `head` should be in `<html>` tag and before `<body>` tag.

Below is a fiddle which works even with wrong tags

http://jsfiddle.net/a8VhR/5/

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
            Goodbye Cruel World!
        </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```