# Why the <content> tag must be defined with a starting and ending tag?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I used these two syntaxes in Firefox/Chrome to define a WebComponent.

**Open tag**

```html
<content></content>
```

**Closed tag**

```html
<content/>
```

and both work as expected.

What are the (technical) reasons for defining `<content>` in the first way?

---

[MDN Content element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content) indicates that a starting and ending tag is **mandatory**, but doesn't specify why.

Comment: Probably something to do with the attributes.

Comment: And plus, I think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170547/is-there-a-content-element-in-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually must use the `<content></content>` form. In a normal HTML (non-XML) document (which is what you want to be making here), with the standard way that HTML parsing works in all browser engines, the `<content/>` tag is *not* a `content` end tag—instead it’s just a `content` start tag with an extra `/` inside it that just gets ignored by HTML parsers.

In your case, that means when an HTML parser doesn’t see any `</content>` end tag for that `content`-start-tag-with-extra-`/`-at-the end, the parser *never actually closes that `content` element*, so that *all nodes that follow that `content` element become child content of it.

To see what I mean, look at the [DOM view of what the `<content/>` looks like to an HTML parser](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Ccontent%2F%3E%0AStuff%20that%20you%20think%20isn%E2%80%99t%20child%20nodes%20of%20the%20%22content%22%20element%20but%20that%20actually%20is.%0A%3Csection%3E%0AMore%20stuff%20that%20you%20think%20isn%E2%80%99t%20child%20nodes%20of%20the%20%22content%22%20element%20but%20that%20actually%20is.%0A%3C%2Fsection%3E%0A%0A%0A).

[image]

> MDN Content element indicates that the empty tag form is mandatory, but doesn't specify why.

I'm not sure what you mean by “empty tag form”. That MDN page says:

> **Tag omission**: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

That means the `content` element *must* have an end tag.