# What is `content` tag in angular2 template

Tags: angular

I'm looking at this `html` from this [app](https://github.com/vsavkin/router_mailapp/blob/master/src/app/mail.html#L11) and it has the following:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="folder">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/inbox">Inbox</li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/drafts">Drafts</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <content>   <------------------------------------------------ what is this?
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </content>
```

What is this `content` tag? I know of `ng-content` tag that is used for content projection inside the shadow root, but what is this `content`?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with angular 2, it's simply a HTML tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

It should not be used anymore though as the MDN docs state...

Comment: I'm not sure about that. _The HTML <content> element is used inside of Shadow DOM as an insertion point._ - angular has specific tags for that, as I mentioned in my question, it's `ng-content`. The app I linked to doesn't use native shadowing

Comment: Yes I get that, it's just that some people use `<content></content>` as normal HTML rendering tags, probably because they mistake it as a tag introduced alongside many other new tags with HTML5: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp (I guess).

Comment: okay, but this guy is a core contributor to angular2, I don't think he mistaken this tag for something else

Comment: I know, that's why I was surprised too, probably he just copy pasted it. I mean worst case it doesn't get rendered, but everything would still work as expected.

Comment: okay, thanks, let's see if someone else has other suggestions

Comment: Angular could treat `<content>` as alias for `<ng-content>`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks, so what you're saying is that it's there on purpose?

Comment: The code is from Victor Savcin, therefore, yes, I'm sure it's there on purpose :D

Comment: He is using that tag in no other repository it seems. Plus he is styling it: https://github.com/vsavkin/router_mailapp/blob/master/src/app/mail.css#L29 
Looks pretty much like a normally used HTML tag to me. Angular wouldn't treat a deprecated tag as an alias IMO. 
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170547/is-there-a-content-element-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the two - a plain html5 tag or more likely an angular2 component.