# How to select elements from <template> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I have two similar selections. The first uses a `<div>` tag, which works fine, the second uses a newly `<template>` tag, which doesn't work anymore.

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work **with jQuery** using the `<template>` tag?

**HTML**

```
<div id="div">
    <div>content</div>
</div>

<template id="template">
    <div>content</div>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $div = $('#div');
var $content = $div.find('div');
console.log($content); //works ($content.length == 1)

var $template = $('#template');
var $content = $template.find('div');
console.log($content); //doesn't work ($content.length == 0)
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/s8b5w0Le/1/

Comment: I'm using Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m (in case it matters)

Comment: `$template[0].outerHTML` works, so it should theoretically be possible for jQuery to work with the `<template>` tag

Comment: So, you cannot use jQuery alone for this work, but you can check if the `content` attribute exists? If so, use it - if not, the regular `jQuery` way should work?

Comment: try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930706/html-template-tag-and-jquery

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`HTMLTemplateElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement) saves the DOM into a separate *attribute*.

**jQuery**

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $div = $('#div');
        var $content = $div.find('div');
        console.log($content.text()); // output "content", inner div

        var $template = $('#template');
        var node = $template.prop('content');
        var $content = $(node).find('div');
        console.log($content.text()); // output "content", inner template
    });
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.createElement('template').content
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly certain this has to do with Chrome's use of shadow dom (thank Polymer... )

You can either try your luck using the `/deep/` combinator (probably won't work on other browsers), but I think the most robust solution would be `$template[0].outerHTML` as in your comment if you just need the text.

If you need jQuery functionality, using `$.parseXML` (to avoid Chrome's native dom construction) would probably do the trick across all browsers (can confirm Chrome + FF).

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3fe9jjfj

```
var tc = $('#template')[0].outerHTML;

$template = $($.parseXML(tc)).contents();

console.log($template);
console.log($template.find('div'));
```

Both logs return as we'd expect, and `$template` can now be treated as an ordinary jQuery object.

Comment: Great, thanks! Sometimes, the best answers come from users with the lowest amount of reputation score ;)

Comment: There is a problem, however, if you have non XML compatible tags (i.e. `<hr>`), you would need to write `<hr/>`, but `outerHTML` still returns `<hr>` - so this might be tricky

Comment: @SimonFerndriger Depending on what your use of template entails, you may be able to alternately get away with using a custom tag name (e.g. `xtemplate`), rather than `template`. If you're using your template to bind data with Handlebars or something, then that should work. Again, hacky, but I guess this is what is expected with early adoption

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, Chrome puts `<template>` child elements into a shadow DOM. To access them:

```
// Access the JavaScript object for the template content
$('template')[0]

// Make a jQuery selection out of it
$($('template')[0])

// Now you can search it
$($('template')[0]).find('div.someclass').css('color','#000');
```

Answer (score 2):

A way, too late for the party but I ended up doing this:

```js
function resolveTemplate(id) {
  return $(id).contents();
}

...

var $searchIcon = resolveTemplate('#search-icon-template');
$('#div').append($searchIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the JQuery methods as usual if the element inside the template element are wrapped with a container.

```js
const temp = $("#template").contents().clone();
$(temp).find("h1").text("A dynamic title");
temp.appendTo($("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="template">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>lorem ipsum </p>
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</template>
```

The container can also be appended dynamically with JQuery. Or if you don't want a container, you can append its content.

```js
const temp = $('<div></div>').html($("#template").contents().clone());
$(temp).find("h1").text('dynamic title');
$(temp).find("p").text('But no container this time');
temp.contents().appendTo($("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="template">
    <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum </p>
    <img src="" alt="">
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
   <div class="template-container">
      <div class="content">content</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

```
var templateHtml = ('#template').html() // this will return the template container div
var template = $(templateHtml);
var content = template.find('.content');

console.log(content);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.

Comment: This only creates a new element with the template code. It doesn't select the actual template content itself. It's a copy essentially. This would not be be helpful for things like manipulating the DOM in the template element.

Comment: your code needs some fixing to get it to work.  Please check your code and make sure it works before posting an answer.

Answer (score -3):

var $content = $template.content.find('div');

... instead of ...

var $content = $template.find('div');

Worked for me.

Comment: OK, and what about Internet Explorer?

Comment: You probably mean `$template[0].content` (from the HTMLObject, not from the jQuery object) - but this doesn't work in Internet Explorer as far as I know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: I did console.log($template) to look at the structure of the template-Tag. In Chrome and Firefox it seems to be different.

Answer (score -3):

HTML5 template is `display: none;` by default, `childNodes` in template is invalid, if you inspect it in console you'll find something different