# how to find element in template tag with need to support all browser in single Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-template

if i use div element inside template tag means how will i find through jQuery selector. **

> i am only knows inside div element "id"

**
please check the below example..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="sample1">
    sdjgvhdbvjdbvkdfvbdhkfvdfv
  </div>
</template> <div id="sample2">hiiervhejvbjefvbejfvefv</div>
```

updated Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/o9LkL3g6/3/

Comment: You want to select the div in the template tag with jQuery? var $div = $("template div"); http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: i know about JQuery selector  inside template tag we can't find element through Jquery..please check it

Comment: Can you update your question with the jQuery code as well?

Comment: please check this fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/o9LkL3g6/

Comment: the code in the fiddle seems to work. Unless your intention is different? If you know the element id then that's sufficient to select it - $("#sample1"). You don't care whether it's inside the template tag or not. Element ids must be unique, so it can't be confused with a different one somewhere else in the page.

Comment: Sorry but right now i don't have much time, but i have founded this question that look similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311226/how-to-select-elements-from-template-with-jquery

Comment: @ADyson   please check that fiddle correctly.....and update it in JsFiddle ...i need output in Chrome and mozilla

Comment: @charlietfl please check that fiddle correctly.....and update it in JsFiddle ...i need output in Chrome and mozilla

Comment: @ADyson which browser do you use? Because in Chrome (53.0.2785.143) it does not work for me

Comment: @ADyson i am using  53.0.2785.116  chrome browser latest only.

Comment: @Marko sorry I was mistaken, it didn't work. Should have looked more closely. The answer you've linked to should provide the solution

Comment: The code is right but problem is in your fiddle. If you change `LOAD TYPE` value to `onLoad` it work. See https://jsfiddle.net/o9LkL3g6/1/

Comment: @Mohammad in Chrome browser it was not working please check it..

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sample2").append($($("template").prop("content")).find("#sample1").html().trim());
});`

That will work.

Explanation:
A template element saves its content into and attribute(property) called content. Therefore we retreive this attribute with jQuery `$("template").prop("content")` then we wrap it in jQuery `$($("template").prop("content"))` on which we can then call jQuery's find function to retrieve element `$($("template").prop("content")).find("#sample1")` after which I get the elements innHTML and trim it so that it matches your wanted output.

Comment: your content is working but when compare to cross browser safari and IE content not perform append performing prepend please check it

Comment: Will check, just per your own comment you needed it working in chrome and firefox "@ADyson please check that fiddle correctly.....and update it in JsFiddle ...i need output in Chrome and mozilla – Pradeep Kumar - 18 hours ago"

Comment: IE Does not support the template tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template ( Edge 13 does )