# jQuery 3.6.0 can't parse "template" tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The other day I's working on a project using jQuery 3.6.0 but I found that it can't parse `<template>` tags.

Refer to the below example.

```js
const temp = $("#main");
console.log(temp.find("div").html()); // this isn't working


const temp2 = $("#main2");
console.log(temp2.find("div").html()); // this is working
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="main">
  <div class="first">
    <span>Hola</span>
  </div>
</template>


<div id="main2" style="display:none;">
  <div class="first">
    <span>Hola</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `<template id="main">` from a framework like vuejs?

Comment: No it's normal HTML. I'm not working with any Framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html template tag and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930706/html-template-tag-and-jquery)

Comment: Yeah I got the solution but it didn't explain why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template` results in a document fragment in which the contents of the `template` element is. You have to access it using `content`.

So what you could do is `$(temp[0].content).find('div').html()`

But you need to be careful about that [MDN: `<template>`: The Content Template element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#attributes):

> However, the HTMLTemplateElement has a `content` property, which is a read-only DocumentFragment containing the DOM subtree which the template represents. Note that directly using the value of the content could lead to unexpected behavior, see Avoiding DocumentFragment pitfall section below.

```js
const temp = $("#main");
console.log($(temp[0].content).find('div').html()); // this isn't working


const temp2 = $("#main2");
console.log(temp2.find("div").html()); // this is working
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="main">
  <div class="first">
    <span>Hola</span>
  </div>
</template>


<div id="main2" style="display:none;">
  <div class="first">
    <span>Hola</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like I got the explanation. Thank you.